# How to delete part of the code in TWIG for Drupal?

Tags: html, drupal, twig, drupal-8

I use this code to print the flag in its node :

```
{{ content.flag_like_node }}
```

When I print my flag in the template of my node, the rendering is as follows :

```
<div class="bs-field-like-link"><a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1"></a><div class="flag flag-like-store js-flag-like-store-13 action-unflag"><a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1"></a><a title="" href="/fr/flag/details/edit/like_store/13?destination=/fr/boutique/poupette-cacahuete" class="use-ajax" data-dialog-type="modal" data-dialog-options="{&quot;width&quot;:&quot;auto&quot;}" rel="nofollow"><span class="btn btn-success"><svg class="svg-inline--fa fa-heart fa-w-16 fa-lg" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="heart" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512" data-fa-i2svg=""><path fill="currentColor" d="M462.3 62.6C407.5 15.9 326 24.3 275.7 76.2L256 96.5l-19.7-20.3C186.1 24.3 104.5 15.9 49.7 62.6c-62.8 53.6-66.1 149.8-9.9 207.9l193.5 199.8c12.5 12.9 32.8 12.9 45.3 0l193.5-199.8c56.3-58.1 53-154.3-9.8-207.9z"></path></svg><!-- <i class="fas fa-heart fa-lg"></i> --> J'aime</span></a></div></div>

<span class="bs-field-like-count">
    2
  </span>
```

I want to print only the following code, how can I delete the unnecessary code with TWIG ?

```
<span class="bs-field-like-count">
    2
  </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the [Flag module](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag)?
If so, override the [template that the module provides](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/flag/blob/8.x-4.x/templates/flag.html.twig).

To override the template, just copy the one from the module and place the copy in your themes templates folder, then just modify it how you want.

Comment: Yes I use the Flag module. But in some cases I have to display only the counter and in other cases I have to display only the link. With the module there is no possibility to select the display mode. In the only solution and to delete part of the code with Twig, if possible.

Comment: Create a preprocess function for the template which sends a variable to the twig template to set if the counter or link should be visible. Then use that variable in the template to either hide or show the different components.

Comment: Turning on twig debugging will help you determine which twig files are being used and what preprocess function names should be.